# create random short string [a-zA-Z0-9]+

Tags: php

What is the best way to create a short (6 chars), random, and with low collison probability? I need to create short links like bit.ly.

The problem of md5, sha1, uniqid etc. is that they don't generate uppercase characters, so I'm looking for a case-sensitive output to have a wider range of possible values...

Comment: Something like `chr(random_int(65, 122))` (plus some massaging of what characters exactly you accept) gives you the best possible randomness possible; whether this is the correct approach to begin with though is debatable.

Comment: good idea but the range should be 48-57, 65-90, 97-122. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: maybe I can just use a mapping array [0=>'a', 1=>'b', ...] and then random_int the index

Comment: Many possibilities… generate random ints until you get one in your desired range, use a simple mapping as you suggest, do a bit of math (if > 57 add 8 to get into 65-90 range, else add 7 to get into 97-122 range etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Hashids](http://hashids.org/) for this kind of thing:

> Hashids is a [small open-source library](https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.js) that generates short, unique, non-sequential ids from numbers.
>
> It converts numbers like 347 into strings like “yr8”, or array of numbers like [27, 986] into “3kTMd”.
>
> You can also decode those ids back. This is useful in bundling several parameters into one or simply using them as short UIDs.

Hashids has been ported to many languages, [including PHP](http://hashids.org/php/).

(Note that, despite the name, Hashids is not a true hashing system since it is designed to be reversible.)